# MCQ(Functional analysis.)

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C[0,1]$ with the norm $\|x\|=\int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|dt,\in C[0,1]$ and $D=\{f\in X^{'}:\|f\|=1\},$ where $X^{'}$ denotes the dual space of $X.$ Let $C(D)$ be the space of continuous functions on $D$ with the norm $\|u\|=sup_{s\in D}|u(s)|,u\in C(D)$ then which of the following is true

$1. X$ is lineraly isomorphic with $C(D).$

$2.X$ is linearly isomorphic with a proper subspace of $C(D).$

$3.$ There does not exist a linear isometry from $X$ to $C(D).$

$4.$ Every linear isometry from $X$ to $C(D)$ is onto.

(I am just started reading functional analysis so for some one  it may be very trivial problem sorry for that ) According to me i studied that $C(D)$ with sup norm is complete but not with $p$ norm with $1\leq p<\infty$. So according to me there does not exist any linear isometry between the two spaces. So correct answer is $C.$ Am i right? Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $f \in X'$ what is $\|f\|$?

Comment: its is given the collection of norm $1$ functionals...

Comment: The space $D$ is not compact. The sup norm on $C(D)$ is probably not well-defined.

Comment: Are the functions in $C(D)$ supposed to be linear?

Comment: obviously linear functional is a linear map..