# Best approximation of a vector in normed linear space $C[0,1.]$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X=C[0,1]$ with the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\int_{0}^{1}x(t) \overline{y(t)}dt,x,y\in C[0,1].$
>
> $X_{0}=\{x\in X:\int_{0}^{1}t^{2}x(t)dt=0\},$ and $X_{0}^{\perp}$ be the orthogonal complement of $X_{0}.$ Let $y(t)=t^{3},t\in [0,1]$ and $x_{0}\in X_{0}^{\perp}$ be the best approximation of $y.$ Then $x_{0}(t)$ is
>
> $A.\frac{4}{5}t^{2}.$
>
> $B.\frac{5}{6}t^{2}.$
>
> $C.\frac{6}{7}t^{2}.$
>
> $D.\frac{7}{8}t^{2}.$

I am trying it as follows

All option are of the form $at^{2}$ so i am trying to find exact value of $a$ for which $\|t^{3}-at^{2}\|$ is least by calculating the integration value. Am i right or there is another exact method to find best approximation in infinite dimensional  normed linear space? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_0$ is the best approximation to $x$ in $X_0^\perp$, then we should have $x = x_0 + x_1$ where $x_1 \in (X_0^\perp)^\perp = X_0$. Using that we're only given alternatives of the form $at^2$, that means that we want
$$
0 = \int_0^1t^2x_1(t) dt = \int_0^1t^2(t^3-at^2)dt \\
= \left[\frac{t^6}{6}-a\frac{t^5}{5}\right]_{t = 0}^1 = \frac16 - \frac a5
$$
which gives $a = \frac56$.

Comment: ok i got it.....thank you very much...

Comment: can you please look at my similar problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888034/mcqfunctional-analysis

Comment: I think it will be very easy for you....Thanks a lot...