# Approach for checking completeness of a subspace of $C[0,1]$ and orthogonality

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality

Let $X=C[0,1]$ be the space of all continuous function on $[0,1]$ with the standard inner product $\langle x,y\rangle= \int_0^1 x(t)y(t)dt,$ for  $x,y \in C[0,1].$
Define $X_0=\{ x \in X : \int_0^1 t^2x(t)dt=0\}.$

(i) What can we conclude on the completeness of the space $X_0$ and its orthogonal complement $X_0^\perp ?$

(ii) Let $y(t)=t^3,t \in [0,1]$ and $x_0 \in X_0 ^\perp$ be the best approximation of $y.$ Then $x_0(t),t \in[0,1]$ is

(a) $\frac{4}{5}t^2$

(b) $\frac{5}{6}t^2$

(c) $\frac{6}{7}t^2$

(d) $\frac{7}{8}t^2$

**My Attempt:**
The second part is already solved here in [Best approximation of a vector in normed linear space $C[0,1.]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888899/best-approximation-of-a-vector-in-normed-linear-space-c0-1).

My idea for the part (ii) is to first find a basis for the space $X_0.$ Then I can project the given function $y(t)=t^3$ onto that space. Using that projection, I can find the difference of the given function $y$ and its projection on $X_0,$ which will give me the required best approximation.
I could not find any basis for $X_0.$
But, I was able to understand the reasoning given in the linked page.
However, what if the options were not given to me?
Is there straight-forward approach to (ii)?

I could not find any approach to part (i).

Please help. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $X_0^{\perp}=\{ct^{2}:c \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: If $C[0,1]$ is complete then $X_0\subset C[0,1]$ is complete if and only if $X_0$ is closed

Comment: @geetha290krm, one way containment relation is straightforward to show. But how can I show the reverse containment i.e., $ct^2 $ are the only elements in $X_0 ^\perp.$ Please elaborate if possible .

Comment: Are you familiar with basic Hilbert space theory? Do you know that $(M^{\perp})^{\perp}=M$ for a closed subspace $M$?

Comment: We know that $C[0,1] $ is not complete under 2-norm which is induced from the given inner product. So that result cannot be used here. However, seeing this result I have an idea. But I don't know whether we can use it here. $L^2[0,1]$ is a complete space under the 2-norm and it has $C[0,1]$ as one of  its subspace. Can we use the transitivity of subspaces and the @David Raveh's result ?

Comment: Yes I have worked out that result. One way is always true i.e., $M \subset (M^\perp)^\perp ,$ even for non-closed subspaces. But how to construct $(M^\perp)^\perp ?$  That's the confusing part.

Comment: I think I have showed that $(X_0^ \perp)^\perp \subset X_0.$ Let $f(t) \in (X_0^ \perp)^\perp.$ Then, $\int_0 ^1 f(t)g(t)dt=0,$ for all $g(t) \in X_0^ \perp.$ For this to work, we need to have $f(t) \in X_0.$ Is this logic correct ??

Comment: There is a slight problem with the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888899/best-approximation-of-a-vector-in-normed-linear-space-c0-1) as it solves the best approximation with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm. I guess you are after $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm.

Answer (score 0):

We should specify what the underlying field ($\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) is, though the conclusion won't change (but complex conjugation would be needed in the definition of the inner product). For one thing, a real complete inner product space is usually not called "Hilbert".

It is well-known that $C([0,1], \mathbb R)$ under the given inner product is not complete, whose completion is $L^2([0,1], \mathbb R)$, the space of Lebesgue square-integrable functions. Given an inner product space $H$ that is not complete, we know $v^{\perp}$ cannot be complete either for any $v\in H$, since otherwise, $H=\mathbb Rv\oplus v^{\perp}$ must be also complete, that is $X_0$ in the problem is NOT complete. And since $(v^{\perp})^{\perp}=\mathbb Rv$, we know $X_0^{\perp}$ is complete.

To show $(v^{\perp})^{\perp}=\mathbb Rv$, obviously we only need to show if $w\in (v^{\perp})^{\perp}$, or equivalently  $(v,x)=0\Rightarrow (w,x)=0$ for all $x$, then $w$ is a multiple of $v$. Here we only need the case $v\not=0$, then we have $(v, w-\frac{(v,w)}{(v,v)}v)=0$ implies $$(w, w-\frac{(v,w)}{(v,v)}v)=0 \Rightarrow (w,w) = \frac{(v,w)^2}{(v,v)}\Rightarrow (w,w)(v,v)=(v,w)^2$$ that is the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is tight, which implies $w,v$ are linearly dependent.

This proves in particular $X_0^{\perp}=\{ct^2:c\in\mathbb R\}$ which is complete, even though $X_0$ is not complete.